# oracle hierarchy that gets wrong reference parent

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below data example for some items, those items have `reference` and `reference parents`. My issue is some references have wrong parents,which lead to infinite loop

let me explain, item with reference `K001` doesn't have reference because it is the main product, reference `k002` its parent is `k001`. `k003` its parents is `k001`, data here is correct, because k001 is the parent with reference `First`.

For type B data is incorrect, `m992` its parent is `m993`, however reference m993 its parent is `m992`, this is incorrect, the `reference` should point to a `reference_parent` `First` so to fix this the `reference_parent` for `reference` m992 should be m991 not m993.

For type C data also is incorrect, reference `K883` has wrong `reference_Parent` because it has`k886`. 
Because when I go to `reference` K886 I check its reference parent which is `k885` then i check `k885` `reference parent` which is `k884` , then i check reference parent for k884 which is k883, then when I check k883 reference parent it gives me k886, here its wrong and I go an infinite loop, because k886 reference parent is kk85. To correct the reference parent of item `k883` should be `k882`

```
        Type   Reference Reference_Parent

        A       K001    First
        A       K002    K001
        A       K003    K001
        B       M991    First
        B       M992    M993  --wrong parent data
        B       M993    M992
        C       K881    First
        C       K882    K881
        C       K883    K886   --wrong parent data
        C       K884    K883
        C       K885    K884
        C       K886    K885 
        A       L001    First
        A       L002    L001
        A       L003    L002
        A       L004    L002
        A       L005    L002
        A       L006    L004
```

I tried with below query but its not giving me my required result and I am not expert with heirachy queries

```
SELECT reference,reference_parent,LEVEL ,SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(reference, '/') "Path"
FROM ITEMS 
WHERE TYPE='B' 
START WITH reference_parent = 'First'
CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR reference_parent = 'First'
```

My required result is to give me

```
        B       M992    M993  --wrong parent data
        C       K883    K886   --wrong parent data
```

Comment: It should be `CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR reference_parent = reference`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did the below and it didn't give my desired output 

SELECT type, reference,reference_parent,LEVEL ,SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(reference, '/') "Path"
FROM ITEMS 
WHERE TYPE='C' 
START WITH reference_parent = 'First'
CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR reference_parent = reference
 it gave C K881 First 1 /K881

Comment: If the Reference_Parent should have a lower number than Reference as it seems in the example, you could filter by that.

Comment: @btpys you mean by levels ? no its not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ITEMS ( Type, Reference, Reference_Parent ) AS
SELECT 'A', 'K001', 'First' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'K002', 'K001'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'K003', 'K001'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'M991', 'First' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'M992', 'M993'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL --wrong parent data
SELECT 'B', 'M993', 'M992'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'K881', 'First' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'K882', 'K881'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'K883', 'K886'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL --wrong parent data
SELECT 'C', 'K884', 'K883'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'K885', 'K884'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'K886', 'K885'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'L001', 'First' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'L002', 'L001'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'L003', 'L002'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'L004', 'L002'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'L005', 'L002'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'L006', 'L004'  FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       MIN( CONNECT_BY_ROOT( Reference_Parent ) )
         KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT( Reference ) )
         AS reference_parent,
       MIN( CONNECT_BY_ROOT( Reference ) )
         AS reference
FROM   ITEMS
START WITH Reference NOT IN (
  SELECT reference
  FROM   ITEMS
  START WITH Reference_Parent = 'First'
  CONNECT BY PRIOR Reference = Reference_Parent
)
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR Reference = Reference_Parent
GROUP BY Reference
```

**Output**:

> ```
> REFERENCE_PARENT | REFERENCE
> :--------------- | :--------
> K886             | K883     
> M993             | M992
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=055840be38a84c60fa7a3bba68bf836a)*

**Explanation**:

You can find all the rows in the hierarchy starting with `'First'` using the query:

```
SELECT reference
FROM   ITEMS
START WITH Reference_Parent = 'First'
CONNECT BY PRIOR Reference = Reference_Parent
```

Your rows will be disconnected from these so you want a hierarchical query like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   ITEMS
START WITH Reference NOT IN (
  SELECT reference
  FROM   ITEMS
  START WITH Reference_Parent = 'First'
  CONNECT BY PRIOR Reference = Reference_Parent
)
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR Reference = Reference_Parent
```

This just gives you the disconnected components and will generate lots of duplicate rows as it will start the hierarchy at every point in the cycle so some additional work is required to find the lowest `Reference` in the cycle (which appears to be where you are saying the wrong parents have occurred). This can be found by getting the `MIN`imum values for `CONNECT_BY_ROOT( Reference )` for each `Reference`; which gives you the query above.

---

**Query 2**:

You could also just look for cycles without eliminating the rows connected to `'First'`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       MIN( Type ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY Reference )
         AS Type,
       MIN( Reference ) AS Reference,
       MIN( Reference_Parent ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY Reference )
         AS Reference_Parent
FROM   (
  SELECT Type,
         Reference,
         Reference_parent,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT( Reference_Parent ) AS root_reference_parent,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT( Reference ) AS root_reference,
         CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE AS isCycle
  FROM   ITEMS
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR Reference = Reference_Parent
)
GROUP BY
       root_Reference,
       root_Reference_Parent
HAVING MAX( isCycle ) = 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f71a4708afe00d6658372d5483d12779)*

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first query was helpful to me however, when I am running it I am geeting error , ora01436-connect by loop in user data. So I created a new table with 1 Type, then i ran the query and it gave me the parent reference, is there a way to handle the error so i can select all the types ? as for the second query it shows wrong result.

Comment: @Moudiz If you run the first query from the explanation does that also generate a `ORA01436 Connect by loop in user data` error? If it does then you've got a cycle in the data when you start from the `'First'` root and can fix it by adding `NOCYCLE` to that `CONNECT BY` part of that sub-query.

Comment: @Moudiz Can you provide some sample data (edit my [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f71a4708afe00d6658372d5483d12779)) where the second one generates wrong data. It may be that because its looking for any cycles in the data and some of the cycles it is finding are connecting to the `'First'` root and you're considering them to be valid data rather than invalid that its slightly too generic a solution for your specific problem (even though it solves your test data) and may need additional filtering. But without knowing the data causing the issue its difficult to say.